# TD Height by Multiples

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have made a text-box with a border in HTML by means of a table. The image that I am tiling for the height of it is 64x64 and only tiles properly when the height is set to a multiple of 64. 128, for example. The text on the inside has its padding set to ten pixels, so that would be 128-20 in order to tile properly. When however much text has been typed, the height obviously changes on its own accord to the point that it does not tile properly. Is there a way to make the height increase by sixty-four pixels whenever more space is needed for the text, or is the only solution to type all of the text and images in advance, count the number of tiles, calculate the height, and use that number for the height? I haven't found any topics like this online yet, so I look forward to everyone's input on having TD height increase in multiples. Thank you!

```
<tr>
<td style="background:url('64x64_Vertical_Image.png'); width:64px; height:64px;"></td>
<td style="width:auto; height:108px; vertical-align:top; padding:10px;">Text here.</td>
<td style="background:url('64x64_Vertical_Image.png'); width:64px; height:64px;"></td>
</tr>
```

The vertical image tiles per sixty-four pixels, so the height must be a multiple of sixty-four, minus twenty for the text padding. In order for it to connect to the corner pieces of the border seamlessly, that is.

Comment: Please provide your code either inline or as a link to http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Thank you for your response, Ben! I added code to the post.

Comment: Why don't you use stylesheets instead of inline styling and divisions (or another element) instead of tables?

Comment: Interesting problem. I thought setting all td `min-height`s to 1px and giving the one with the text `rowspan=64` would help, but that didn't do anything. Not sure there is an solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about using javascript for this? Check the height of the text cell, divide by 64, round up with Math.ceil and multiply with 64 again.